# getting a specific XML tag element in Java

Tags: java, xml, nodes, getelementsbytagname, nodelist

I have the following XML:

```
<oa:Parties>
  <ow-o:SupplierParty>
    <oa:PartyId>
      <oa:Id>1</oa:Id>
    </oa:PartyId>
  </ow-o:SupplierParty>
  <ow-o:CustomerParty>
    <oa:PartyId>
      <oa:Id>123-123</oa:Id> // I NEED THIS
    </oa:PartyId>
    <oa:Business>
      <oa:Id>ShiptoID</oa:Id>
    </oa:Business>
  </ow-o:CustomerParty>
</oa:Parties>
```

How can I get the `123-123` value?

I tried this:

```
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("ow-o:CustomerParty");
Node parentNode = nodeList.item(0);
String ID = parentNode.getTextContent();
```

But it has both `<oa:Id>` elements.

Is there a way to find the value based on hierarchy `ow-o:CustomerParty > oa:PartyId > oa:Id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d just go with A simple filter on its child items. This way

```
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("ow-o:CustomerParty");
Node parentNode = nodeList.item(0);

Node partyNode = filterNodeListByName(parentNode.getChildNodes(), "oa:PartyId");

Node idNode = null;
if(partyNode!=null)
    idNode = filterNodeListByName(partyNode.getChildNodes(), "oa:Id")

String ID = idNode!=null ? idNode.getTextContent() : "";
```

Basically the first filter gets all the child items matching the node name "oa:PartiId". It then maps the found node (I used findAny but findFirst could still be a viable option in your case) to the child item node's, with name oa:id, text content

SN: I’m considering you’ll define a method such so

```
public boolean isNodeAndWithName(Node node, String expectedName) {
    return node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && expectedName.equals(node.getNodeName());
}
```

And this is the additional method

```
public Node filterNodeListByName(NodeList nodeList, String nodeName) {
        for(int i = 0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++)
            if(isNodeAndWithName(nodeList.item(i), nodeName)
                return nodeList.item(i);
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this solution but looks like `NodeList` does not have `stream()`. I am getting an error `error: cannot find symbol:   method stream() location: interface NodeList`

Comment: My bad I'm used to a library which gave you the list I'm gonna fix it right away

Comment: @AJ let me know, this is adapted to default NodeList object

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Just wanted to point out in case someone else comes across it, the method is `getChildNodes()`, not `getChildItems()`. And the `isNodeWithName` method name does not match, so you can edit your question if you like with those changes. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks my bad, copying the code I lost some parts